# What are the differences between `./build.sbt` and `./project/build.sbt`?

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt

For example, I want to set a key in the build definition, which one should I put the setting in? The `build.sbt` in the root directory? Or the `build.sbt` in `project` directory?

I think both will work. Is there any reason that I could prefer one to the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's *almost* no difference between `build.sbt` and `project/build.sbt` -- they're both `build.sbt` after all, but their location makes a difference in how and what part of the project build they're configuring.

Quoting [sbt is recursive](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Full-Def.html#sbt+is+recursive):

> The `project` directory is *another project inside your project* which
>   knows how to build your project. The project inside `project` can (in
>   theory) do anything any other project can do. *Your build definition is
>   an sbt project.*
>
> And the turtles go all the way down. If you like, you can tweak the
>   build definition of the build definition project, by creating a
>   `project/project/` directory.

There are two direct ways to set up a build for your project using sbt - with `.sbt` files in the main directory of your project and `project/*.scala` files. All these files constitute the build.

There's however a way to set up a build for the build you've just configured and the same rules apply - you can use (note `project` directory before the locations) `project/*.sbt` and `project/project/*.scala` files.

[And the turtles go all the way down.](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Full-Def.html#sbt+is+recursive)

To extend your project's build you may want to use sbt plugins - a build configuration bundled together to ease its installation. They're a part of the build of the build of your project (*the build* was doubled on purpose). By convention, the plugins are installed in `project/plugins.sbt`, but *any* `.sbt` file beneath `project` directory would be fine.

To make the story short, if you *want to set a key in the build definition*, you should use `.sbt` or `project/*.scala` files at the level that would correspond to the build definition. If that's the *top-level* build definition of your project, go for *`build.sbt` in the root directory*.

Remember that any build definition under `project` becomes a part of the build definition of your project. [And the turtles go all the way down][3], remember?

Answer (score 8):

The `project` folder should not contain `build.sbt`, only `plugins.sbt` and `.scala` files. The Scala files are typically used to create some common object with vals that are used in several builds throughout your project. I also usually create a `dev.sbt` that contains plugins that I'm using for development, and that file stays out of version control.

Comment: Why don't you place `dev.sbt` under `~/.sbt/0.13`? It's gonna save you much time setting up the dev sbt config for other projects in the future.

Comment: Not every project should load these plugins, and not every project is compatible with every plugin version. Global plugin settings only make things complicated.

Comment: Valid point. That's what I think is exactly the reason for autoplugins = so an end user doesn't need to know about plugin dependencies.